# loop only showing first value when using variable

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, product-attribute, array, variables

I am trying to show products that are added in a custom attribute in the backend but it is only showing the first item

```
<?php
$bundle_products = $_product->getbundle_products();
if ($_product->getAttributeText('bundle') == yes):
$product_ids = array($bundle_products);
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $product_ids));

foreach($collection as $eachproduct){
echo '<a href="' . $eachproduct->getProductUrl() . '"><img  src="' . $eachproduct->getImageUrl() . '" title="' . $eachproduct->getName() . '" height="50" width="50"></a>';
$combined_price += $eachproduct->getFinalPrice()/100*10;
}
endif;
?>
```

If I hard code it in as: `$product_ids = array(3,138,194);`
It works fine. Am I missing something?

If I echo `$bundle_products` It outputs 3,138,194

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code:

```
<?php
    $bundle_products = $_product->getbundle_products();
    if ($_product->getAttributeText('bundle') == yes):
    //$product_ids = array($bundle_products);
    $product_ids = explode(',',$bundle_products);
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $product_ids));

    foreach($collection as $eachproduct){
    echo '<a href="' . $eachproduct->getProductUrl() . '"><img  src="' . $eachproduct->getImageUrl() . '" title="' . $eachproduct->getName() . '" height="50" width="50"></a>';
    $combined_price += $eachproduct->getFinalPrice()/100*10;
    }
    endif;
    ?>
```

You are almost did all things right. Only you need to convert the string into array. that's why i use `explode(',',$bundle_products)`.

***Hope it will solve your problem. Happy learning***

Comment: Thank you so much :) will have to have a look into explode.

Comment: And let me know if that work

Comment: Yes it worked. I have to wait a few minutes to accept the answer. good work.